# Safe way to call sh script recursively

Tags: linux, bash

So I found out the hard way doing this is really bad in linux:

```
# a.sh
while true
do
  some stuff
  sh a.sh
done
```

I want to be able to update the script and have it fix itself. Is something like this considered safe instead/

```
# a.sh
while true
do
  wget http://127.0.0.1/b.sh
  sh b.sh
done

# b.sh
some stuff
```

This way I can update script `b.sh` and the next execution of it will be force updated since `a.sh` calls it?

Comment: You want to update a script while it is running? Don't. The file handle will still be referenced by the running script so updates won't work.

Comment: No, my apologies. I want it to update on the next running of the script. When the while loop iterates again.  I could even force script A to update script B while script B is not running.

Comment: I wouldn't call your approach safe. Why are you doing this? What **exactly** are you fixing?

Comment: Was going to use wget to update script B from a web server and be able to patch simple updates to 50-100 different' screen's running these sh scripts.

Comment: Okay... so why didn't you post that code? And, what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Well I had originally tried the recursive approach...but that led to fork bombing issues with the OS. So I wanted to validate my second idea before trying it.

Comment: Have you considered putting the files into source control and updating it from there? svn, cvs, rcs, mercurial, git, etc. Finally, why are you looping?

Comment: Looping because the application reboots itself on occasion, so it needs to be turned back on when it reboots.  I have it under source control already, but it's too much to manage still. Was just trying to verify that I wouldn't be creating a fork bomb with the new bash script I had designed in the question.

Comment: Could easily cause a fork bomb. I still don't understand why you're doing this. If it should be restarted on reboot your while loop won't do that.... you could add an `@reboot` entry to cron, you could create an init script....

Comment: Another minor point worth taking a note of: `wget http://some-server/some-file.sh` : will download the file & save it as `some-file.sh` Next time, since the file is already present it will be saved as `some-file.sh.1`. Make sure that you take care of this point..

Answer (score 0):

If you want a process to alter its source code and re-launch itself, and you don't want multiple (slightly different) copies of the process running at the same time, then you somehow need to kill the parent process. It doesn't matter much how you do this; for instance, if the "rewrite self" section of the code is only triggered when a rewrite is actually necessary, then you could just put "exit" after the line that calls the rewritten script. (I suspect that something like `mv -f b.sh a.sh && sh a.sh && exit` might work, too, since I think the entire line would be sent to the Bash interpreter before the script is destroyed.)

If you do want multiple copies of the process running, then you need to find some way to limit this number. For instance, you might have the script check how many iterations of itself are already running before forking.

Note that in both cases, this assumes that your script has accurately modified itself, which...is a tricky problem, to say the least. You are treading on dangerous ground.

Finally, if all you really want is a daemon that gets automatically relaunched when it dies (which is what it sounds like you're describing in your comments), there are other ways to accomplish this. I'm not terribly familiar with how this sort of thing is typically done, but I imagine that in a shell script you could simply use `trap`. (`trap a.sh EXIT` might be sufficient, though that would make your script *quite* difficult to permanently kill should you later decide that you made a mistake.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to `exec` the script. `exec` replaces the script in execution with a new execution environment, so it never returns (unless there was some problem starting the indicated program).

Unless you know what you're doing, it's a bad idea to overwrite a running script. bash does not read the entire file into memory when it starts a script, so it will continue at the same byte offset in the overwritten file.

Finally, don't use `sh` when you mean `bash`. `sh` might be a different shell, and even if it is `bash`, it will have different behaviour.